# too long Base64 image won't display with expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, image, expo, base64

I've been trying a couple ways, but I couldn't make it work. I'm receiving a Base64 image from my backend, but since it's too big, it doesn't display in my expo app. Smaller Base64 images work well, then I suppose it might be about the Base64 string length. It doesn't show any errors, but it's a blank space where the image was supposed to be. Any explanations on why and maybe solutions?

Big images from local directory worked well using 'require()', and so did smaller images as Base64 string. I know I shouldn't be using Base64 images so far, since I could've been using buckets or even public directories, but I can't change it right now.

Comment: It is going to be near impossible to actually help you without any code that shows the problem you are describing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.